# Last activity for intent prior to going to background

Tags: android

When an alarm notification goes off and I activate the app from the notification, I want my application to resume at the same activity as when it was pushed into the background.

Right now, the `PendingIntent` is coded as follows:

```
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MyAppActivity.class), 0);
```

This always resumes at the main activity `MyAppActivity`.

How can I make it resume at the last activity before it was pushed into the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One other way could be setting the flag of the intent FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK.
Havent tried this. But this could work.

You could go through this. It has most of the scenarios related to app switching.
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Doesn't work. My guess is that it only works with startActivity() or startActivityForResult(). For notifications, I'm S.O.L.

Comment: I tried using PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT for pi. No luck.

Comment: Solved. I needed to set launchMode to "singleTask" in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is when your activity is pushed to the background save a preference that ill tell you what state (activity) your application is in. Then when the application resumes, if it can find a previous state, just start that activity.

Comment: Well, there's an additional issue. When the app resumes, it stacks the new activities on top of the previous ones (prior to going to HOME). For example, if previously, main activity A -> B, and then you go to HOME, when the app resumes and let's say we get A -> B again, then the stack looks like this: A -> B -> A -> B. That's just plain weird. Moreover, the first A and B are sort of orphaned.